# Decreasing one dimension of a tensor in Lua Torch

Tags: torch

I have a tensor X of the shape

```
(2,[...])
```

where the three dots can be any vector of dimensions (i.e: 4,4)

I would like to transform this tensor to a tensor whose shape is

```
(1,[...])
```

In other words, I want to reduce the dimensionality of the first dimension. Of course, I will loose the information indexed by 2 but it does not matter in this case. The problem is not trivial as I don't know the number of dimensions of the tensors. But at least it's greater or equal to 2. A th code is written below:

```
th> x = torch.Tensor(2, 4, 4):fill(1)
th> y = x[1]
th> z = torch.Tensor()
th> z[1] = y -- bad argument #1 to '?' (empty tensor at /home/ubuntu/torch/pkg/torch/generic/Tensor.c:684)
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> I want to reduce the dimensionality of the first dimension

If by reducing you mean [narrow down](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/1d4047e/doc/tensor.md#self-narrowdim-index-size) then you can do e.g.:

```
x = torch.Tensor(2, 4, 4)
x[1]:fill(0)
x[2]:fill(1)

-- this creates tensors of size 1x4x4
-- the first dimension is narrowed, one index at a time
a = x:narrow(1, 1, 1)
b = x:narrow(1, 2, 1)
```

This gives:

```
> print(a)
(1,.,.) = 
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x4x4]

> print(b)
(1,.,.) = 
  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x4x4]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you need:

```
y = x[{{1, 1}, {}, {}}]
```

The unknown number of dimensions? Not a problem, you don't have to specify them all:

```
y = x[{{1, 1}}]

(1,.,.) = 
  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x4x4]
```